# How to Set a Limit on Echo?

Tags: php, echo, limit

Needed help here on how to set limit for my table. I just want the first and single value but i couldnt find solution on this.

As i have inserted dates and times in my table. So it looks like this, it has repeated values for both Date and Time.

Date : 19-11-1819-11-18

Time : 05:21:0705:32:10

I just want single value for both Date and Time. Here is my codes.

Date :

```
<?php
        mysqli_data_seek($results, 0);// second instance
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
          echo $row['check_date'];
        }
        ?>
```

Time :

```
<?php
        mysqli_data_seek($results, 0);// second instance
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
          echo $row['check_time'];
        }
        ?>
```

Appreciate for your help!

Comment: Is the value in your database actually `19-11-1819-11-18`? Why is it doubled? Also, where is your query? Why are you not fetching both time and date in one go? Are you storing the date and time as strings? Why not use date and time types? You should also let us know what actually happens when you run your code. What is the actual issue with it?

Comment: It supposed to be only 19-11-18, but it is because i have two columns with the same date, and i could only fetch both values, which that is why it got doubled. Still looking for solution on how to limit the value using echo. I just wanted the first single date.

Comment: Im sorry Im very new to php. ;(

Comment: Just select the columns you need and echo those columns? Not sure what the actual issue is. Or do you mean that you have two _rows_ with the same date? That's a big difference. If you just want the first, just add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query. The question is still a bit unclear.

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson mentioned, it seems like your problem is on the query not PHP. You could do the `LIMIT 1` as he suggested or you could do something like `SELECT DISTINCT check_time FROM check_table`.

Answer (score 1):

Use substr() to only show the first 'n' of your output

```
echo substr($row['check_date'],0,8);
```

but really, as Magnus says, you need to work out why your database is storing the date/time twice and consider moving to using actual datetime fields instead.

Comment: This won't fix anything. Currently the `echo` statement gets run twice because there's 2 rows. It's on a single line because OP didn't add a new line. Using `substr` doesn't do anything here.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, but the simplest with just the lines of code you have is to not use a loop - if you want 1 value then just fetch 1 row of data...

```
mysqli_data_seek($results, 0);// second instance
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
echo $row['check_date'];
```

One thing I would suggest is that it may be easier also to just fetch the data in one place.  Now you've fetched the data into `$row` you can latter on just echo out the data already retrieved...

```
echo $row['check_time'];
```

although you may be safer to read it into something with a more unique name so that you don't re-use the `$row` and loose the values...

```
mysqli_data_seek($results, 0);// second instance
$checkData = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
echo $checkData['check_date'];
```